# Report Designer - Table does not exist?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a report in Report Designer. It uses three tables: SOShipment, SOShipLine, and Inventory Item. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
System.Exception: The table SOShipLine does not exist.
```

But SOShipLine definitely exists. It's a core part of Acumatica, I got it from the instance in the Schema Builder, and I even double-checked the database to be absolutely sure that it exists. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I had an invalid filter. I had `Value1` as `[@StartDate]`, when it should have been either `@StartDate` or `=[@StartDate]`. The error it gave me was very confusing, though.

Comment: Had the exact same typo.  Thank you!